# post categories

Tags: posts, categories, pages

I have posts which i would like to put in to 3 categories News, Events, and Press Releases, then i have three pages which are using the same template. I would like to display those posts on to relevant pages so News posts on News page etc. 
Could someone tell me what would be the best way to do that.

I guess its something easy but I'm fairly new to Wordpress.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the category pages WordPress generates using the `category.php` template, or `category-{slug}.php`. If you don't like the /category/categoryname/ url format WP uses, there are a few plugins that remove the category base- I use Yoast SEO plugin for this, which gives you lots of other great features on top.

Your other option is to create a special template for these pages with some additional code to load posts from your category. [The WP Codex actually has exactly this code for you](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts) already, using a custom field on each page to designate which category you'd like it to load.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Milo
I was thinking more about approche like that 

`if ( is_page('news') ) {
  query_posts('cat=7');
} elseif is_page('events') ) {
  query_posts('cat=9');
}



 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
       
         <?php the_title(); ?>
             
     <?php the_content(); ?> 
        
 <?php endwhile;?> 
` 

but for some reason that doesn't work

Comment: is this the only loop on your page or are you displaying the page's content above this in the template via another loop? `query_posts` is for modifying the main query on a page, not for multiple loops. you'll get unpredictable results due to global variables being set up for your original query. `WP_Query` should be used instead for additional loops. otherwise, it should work, though paging won't unless you explicitly retrieve and pass the paged variable. again, have a look at the code I posted from the Codex, and look up the differences between `query_posts` and `WP_Query`.

Comment: That is the only loop on that particular template

Comment: ok i managed to to it simply just like that 
'<?php if (is_page('News in brief')){ ?>           
                                
             <?php  query_posts('posts_per_page=5&category_name=news&paged='.$paged); ?> ...'
Thanks for all your help